# coding style - image links with description

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I'm wondering how to format my code. which one is better?

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
<img src="http://localhost/g3.jpg" alt="" height="90" width="150">
Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
<img src="http://localhost/g3.jpg" alt="" height="90" width="150">
</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go with the first one unless you have a specific reason for having two links. Don't think about it in terms of proper coding style, but rather what makes sense usability-wise.

Note that you also have the option to *only* use the text in the link, and set the image as the link's `background-image` property in CSS. In many cases, that's exactly what I would do unless the image itself is essential to understanding the link.

In cases like this, the best thing is to think, "Which HTML structure most accurately represents how I want a user to perceive this element?"

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to get :

- If you only want one link *(which, I suppose, is the case, here ?)*, then go with the first solution
- If you want two distinct links *(not sure why you'd want that here, as both point to the same location)*, then go with the second solution.

Here, you want the `<img>` and the text to link to the same page -- so, I'd say it's more logical to only use one `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

The first one makes more sense to me (*since you want both image and text to be part of the link, i see no reason to make two links*).